# SSL certificate sometimes stops working

Tags: security, iis, ssl, certificate

Sometimes, mostly at nighttime, our SSL certificates just stop working.
The error accompanying this fault is:

*A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential **private key**. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 10001.*

To solve this at the moment, we just change the SSL binding of the faulting website to a different site, save it and switch it back. That way, the certificate is picked up again and works (magic).

The question is: **How can we prevent this from happening?** Every time this happens (now twice in the last 6 months), the sites are down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An article I found resolved the issue: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/error-hresult-0x80070520-when-adding-ssl-binding-in-iis/ba-p/377281

FYI, we have checked all three options.

If this error should come up again, I will post it here.

Comment: I had the same issue, and it happened every 3 hours! At least every day... I spend too much time to resolve such a stupid problem, and yes, I used the same solution :) Now the question is: which of this 3 Scenarios fixed my problem? and the second: How to apply this fixes programmatically?

Comment: Applied permission to the folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys" and it worked.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I too have had this problem. My server service was working fine for hours if in use but if left for 45 minutes without a call, it would get this error. So there was some sort of timeout or other expiry occurring. I wrote a utility to monitor my service, and of course that kept it alive. So I adjusted times, and found the period that let it fail. I re-examined all the web references I'd used, and found that re-reading the article at [paulstovell.com](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2) it mentioned the `PersistKeySet` property. Changing my code which prepares the certificate to include this, so it is now like:

```
  X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(file, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

has fixed the problem, and the certificate no longer expires or times out with the 0x8009030d error. And of course this makes sense, as the error is about there being no key, and persisting it is what is required.

http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2

Comment: I tried the `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(file, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);` solution and the private key still disappears after about 30-40 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to a missing permission given on the private keys of the certificate itself in the certificates store:

in certmgr > right click on the certificate > All tasks > Manage Private Keys

Allow the user consuming the certificate (like a service user or whatever).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your final sentence?  I'm not seeing anything like "allow the user..." What I see is a "Certificate purposes" section where "enable all purposes" radio button is the chosen one.

Comment: @Tim Looks like you went to Properties instead of All tasks > Manage Private Keys

Comment: @MatFergusson  I double checked. When I open certmgr on the server, go to Trusted Root Certification Authorities,  click on the certificates folder under that node, and then right-click on the certificate in question in the right-hand pane, choose All Tasks, I get a submenu with "Open" and "Export" options.  If I chose "open",  there is no Manage Private Keys option on any of the three tabs,  General, Details, or Certification Path.

Comment: @Tim It sounds like the you only have the public key for the certificate you are trying to manage. I don't know if there are ever exceptions but The Trusted Root Certification Authorities node would usually only have public keys because it is meant for verifying public websites. This "fix" is meant for certificates in the Personal store.

Answer (score -1):

by editing the permission on `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` I have resolve the same issue thanks

Comment: editing to what???